# Where to load custom usercontrol from?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Which asp.net lifecycle is best for loading a custom usercontrol?

Comment: Should have googled first, coz everyone here has his own opinion her at SO

Comment: Depends on what you are going to do with it (ie:postbacks, do you need events triggered...etc)?

Comment: Just for displaying additional html. I have it in the page load for now, and it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The ASP.NET Page Life Cycle document on MSDN is pretty in describing the events and what are operations should happen in which events.  I'd start there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will clearly explains the [loading of user controls](http://forums.asp.net/t/1191194.aspx)......